# Android Manifest not accepted by Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, manifest

I require some assistance with publishing to Google Play. My game was having issues being run on Android 12 and above, so I adjusted the manifest accordingly and tried to publish it. Alas, I keep getting two errors: It says that I don't have android:exported property set for my activities and services, but I slapped the property on all the activities properly. And when that error doesn't show up, google warns me that the NativeBridgeActivity is foreign intent and is harmful, and must be removed (however the game cannot run without it). They warned me that I have until April to fix it or be removed from Google Play, so I'm panicking a bit because after contacting the google developer support team, they just ignored what I said in the email and repeated themselves with no help or solution. Here is the Manifest:

```html
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.XiaoKhanGames.GuttingGoblins"
     android:versionCode="42"
     android:versionName="1.4" >
 
 
 
   <application>
 
     <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
         android:value="\u0031011141426263" 
                android:exported="true"/>
 
     <!--meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" /-->
 
     <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
         android:value="\u0030.10.14" 
                android:exported ="false"/>
 
 
     
 
 
     <activity android:name="com.XiaoKhanGames.GuttingGoblins.UnityPlayerActivity"
               android:exported="false" />
 
     <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
               android:exported="false"
              android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"/>
              
   
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
               android:exported="false"/>
   
     <activity android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
               android:exported ="true"/>
 
     <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
               android:exported="false"/>
 
     
 
 
     <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" 
                android:exported="true"/>
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: while i understand your frustration, at the end of the day THEY have to accept your app, best we can do here is help you guess what would make them do that, so there isn't much we can do here to help

Comment: Share your NativeBridgeActivity code

Comment: So I took out the NativeBridgeActivity Code altogether but Google Play's still saying that "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported". And yet as you can see in the manifest, they are all with the exported property.